# Running a 32bit executable on a 64bit Ubuntu Oneric

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit

I am trying to run a 32-bit executable on my 64-bit Ubuntu. Here a short overview of the situation. But I have to prepend ia32 libs are installed:

```
> aptitude search ia32
i   ia32-libs - ia32 shared libraries for use on amd64 and ia64 syste
```

First of all I tested the filetype:

```
> file tipp10
tipp10: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
```

I am using 64bit Oneric, with the not so recent kernel, because I didn't restart it yet.

```
> uname -a
Linux christchurch 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As I said normal execution doesn't work. It aborts with file or directory not found.

```
> strace ./tipp10
execve("./tipp10", ["./tipp10"], [/* 46 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
[...]
```

Here is the ldd output on my system. On my 64bit Debian Server the programm is reconized as a dynamic linked programm and a few lib references can be seen in the output. But on my Ubuntu:

```
> ldd tipp10
    \tdas Programm ist nicht dynamisch gelinkt
# german for: "The programm is not linked dynamic"
```

I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Interesting case, installing 'ia32-libs' actually solved it *for me* - ie, I'm able to run 32bit apps natively, sans virtualization. Maybe try running `sudo aptitude reinstall ia32-libs`?

Comment: Reinstalling didn't work. I had one warning: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ia32-libs.postinst: 40: /usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: not found `. But this doesn't look related.

Comment: Indeed it isn't. Are you using oneiric? (Reason I ask is, if you're using an upcoming release, things may be broken out of the box, hence why it isn't recommended to use prereleases of ubuntu)

Comment: It is definitely oneiric (10.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have libc6-i386 correctly installed; `ENOENT` from `execve` suggests a missing dynamic linker.

Comment: Was installed, but a reinstall fixed it. Thank you very much.